# What's default path for "db2move export" command's output

Tags: db2

What's default path for "db2move export" command's output in Linux RedHat 7.2 and how to change it to specific folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- Create directory anywhere you want through the Terminal Command

## mkdir my_export

2- Open the created directory

## cd my_export

3- Run the db2move and export command as per below then you will find all your files in this directory

## db2move YOUR_DB_NAME export

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path(s) for `lob` and `xml` columns with the `-l` parameter of the [db2move](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html) utility only.
Other files will be created in the current directory and this can't be changed.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your great help. I already tried the -l parameter to specify the lob and xml columns and the other files created in the current directory but not all of them so I explored a way to export all the files anywhere you want and I'll post it now